# Union of Different Types of stream in Flink by BaseType

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

Can We have union of two different type of stream but they having common base type ? For example for say
The order events comes like

```
OrderEvent: extends Event
{
userId: Int
Shape: 
Color:  
qty:
string name(); //return orderEvent
}
```

And tick event be like

```
TickEvent: extends Event
{
 Shape:
 Color:
 Price: 
 Location:
 string name() //return tickEvent 
}
```

Considering both are some kind of event, what if I have a Event class from which all the events are derived from. The event class would look like

```
Event:
{
 Shape:
 Color:
 string name(); //return event 
}
```

Can we join these stream by union ? like

```
DataStream<Event> eventStream = orderStream.union(tickstream);
```

And when I receive these event in a operator I use name method to find which type of event it is and do the processing accordingly ?

Answer (score 0):

Would be easier to combine these using Flink's existing [Either](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/api/java/org/apache/flink/types/Either.html) class.

Comment: For two stream yes, what if there are more such Event stream ?

Comment: If you wanted to extend to more possible types, you could obviously create an Either3 (and so on). To use a base class, I think you'd have to create your own custom SerDe to handle serialization/deserialization of the various types of objects (unless you never partition the stream).

Comment: Is there something called Either3 in flink ?

Comment: No, you'd have to create it (using Either as a starting point)

Answer (score 0):

You could just map your OrderEvent and TickEvent streams to Event streams and then union them, like:

```
DataStream<Event> eventDataStream = orderStream
                    .map((MapFunction<OrderEvent, Event>) event -> event)
                    .union(tickStream.map((MapFunction<TickEvent, Event>) event -> event));
```